# How to increase tick label width in d3.js axis

Tags: d3.js

Which parameter should I change to modify the tick label width in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304#index.html)? I have big numbers and few digits are cut...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space for the labels is determined by the left margin of the plot:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
```

All you need to do to give it more space is increase the number, e.g.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 100},
```

Complete demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/1a37ccbf8693f9cc7992). You may also want to consider formatting your labels differently so that they don't use up as much space, see [the `.tickFormat()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat).