# Y-axis ticks' labels visible partially

Tags: d3.js

Which parameter should I manipulate to have whole labels visible here? As you see, hundreds are displayed as "00", "20" and so on:

[image]

Comment: if i understand correctly, try using a format in your axis : d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickFormat(d3.format(".2s")); for example, check the documentation [link](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md) for more info

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the matter of format. The image was too narrow to fit inside SVG canvas and I had to manipulate margins' and padding settings.

Comment: yeah i was thinking of that also, but wasn't sure, glad that you get your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a related question linked here: [How to increase tick label width in d3.js axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322535/how-to-increase-tick-label-width-in-d3-js-axis?rq=1)

Eventually it lead me to this piece of code (`padding` was already defined in my script):

```
var padding = 25;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 60},
                    width = 560 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Manipulating these values (margins and padding) finally gave me the result I wanted: the Y-axis labels are visible:

[image: Solved]